# How to populate data dynamically into the Spinner from the server?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I have got a problemI want to show the list in spinner matched with data entered in the Edittext.
For Example: If we enter the train number in the editext after clicking the button. All stations corresponding to that train number populate as a list in the spinner.
Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand regarding your question is you have an edit text and a button and on clicking button you want to get matched train as the text is available in edit text. If this is the case, i can suggest you to do following.
1) first get the text on the button click call back
2) There should be a web service that should use your text which was collected in step one from edit text 
3) this web service will retrieve data from server according to the sent text
4) Once response is fetched then parse that response 
5) After parsing that response fill the data in adapter 
6) And use that adapter in spinner

Happy coding....